# C# MVC - Counting / Count Up Value automatically

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to count up a value automaticly in my MVC-App. Where have I to do this? In `View` or in `Controller`? Or in Both? The value that I want to count up, is a projectnum,ber with datatype `Integer`.

Here is an example, how I do this in `MS Access / VBA`:

First I look for the highest `Project-Number` and write it into table:

```
Dim projectNR As Long
Dim strSQL As String

projectNR = Nz(DMax("Project_Number", "dbo_Project"), 99999999) + 1
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_Project (Project_Number, Pos) VALUES (" & projectNR & ", 999);"
```

This `Event` is in a `Button` in a form in `MS Access`. It opens the create form. In this form there is another `Event`:

```
Dim RR As Long
RR = DMax("Project_Number", "dbo_Project")
Me.Project_Number = RR
```

When the user save the new row, the Temp-Project-Number will be deleted in table. This is the Workaround for all users, because it is a `Multi-User-Application` in `MS-Access`. It works fine, no double Project-Number in MS Access.

How can I do something like this in MVC?

**UPDATE:**

My table (simple example):

```
|ID|ProjectNo|Pos|
```

ID is PrimaryKey. ProjectNo is INT not nullable. Pos is Int not nullable. When the users begin to work with the app, in DB is a temp. row like this:

```
|ID|ProjectNo|Pos|
------------------
| 1|2017000  |  1|
```

The first user goes into the Create-View. In the view the ProjectNo now should be automaticly 2017001. He can save his date with n positions. After saving the table should look like:

```
|ID|ProjectNo|Pos|
------------------
| 1|2017000  |  1|
------------------
| 2|2017001  |  1|
------------------
| 3|2017001  |  2|
------------------
```

The next user get the 2017002 and so on...

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my `Controller-Code` (Create-Get):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    using (Stamm_Retoure dc = new Stamm_Retoure())
    {
        var v = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(v);
    }
}
```

And here I Need to query the last highest ProjectNo and counter it +.

In VBA I use DMax, please look above...

**Update 3:**

With your comments I tried something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    using (Stamm_Retoure dc = new Stamm_Retoure())
    {
        var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.OrderBy(a => a.Retoure_Nummer).ToList();
        var last = n.Last();

        //var retoure = new HN_Retoure_Stamm() { Retoure_Nummer = last };

        var v = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(v);
    }
}
```

But when I set a `Breakpoint` on `var last`, it is `NULL`, why? And when I uncomment the `var retoure`, then there is an error about `= last`. VS sasy: "CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'int'"...

**Update 4:**

Now my code in `Controller` Looks:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    using (Stamm_Retoure dc = new Stamm_Retoure())
    {
        var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.OrderByDescending(a => a.Retoure_Nummer);
        var last = n.ToArray().Last();

        var retoure = new HN_Retoure_Stamm() { Retoure_Nummer = last };

        var v = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(v);
    }
}
```

But in var retoure the last in { ... = last } is marked red --> Cannot implicitly... Why?

**UPDATE 5:**

Now with the following code it work, but not finaly:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    using (Stamm_Retoure dc = new Stamm_Retoure())
    {
        var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.ToList().Select(a => a.Retoure_Nummer).Last();
        var last = n + 1;

        var retoure = new HN_Retoure_Stamm() { Retoure_Nummer = last };

        var v = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(v);
    }
}
```

Now `var last = n + 1;` = 2017002. Because in DB is at the Moment only 2017001.

**BUT:**

The `Create-View` don't show/display the new Value. It is a `Popup-View`... How can I get the automatic value 2017002 Show on View?

Comment: You do not want to put "business logic" in a view. The view should only deal with representational concerns.

Comment: What's your db? Do you need project numbers to be consecutive?

Comment: Database is a SQL Server 2008 R2. The table have a ID / Primary Key. The Project-Number is Integer (ID is not Project-Number) . This Project-Number should be counting. Later in table there are for example rows like: 2017001 with Pos. 1 and 2017001 with Pos. 2. The next user can have 2017002 with Pos. 1. The enxt user 2017003 with Pos. 1 to 3 and so on...

Comment: Sounds like you want to use custom numbering with "auto-increment"? Don't set the PK as identity column, you need to query the last value saved in DB from controller action & adding 1 to it. The added key value will save to DB when user doing form submit.

Comment: If you're doing something like @TetsuyaYamamoto suggested, then also add a unique key to the table otherwise you'll get duplicate records.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto. Yes I want something like this. Please look a UPDATE in my Post.

Comment: @Vegeta_77 For what interval the `ProjectNo` should be kept (once for `000`, twice for `001` suffix or anything else; in this case your ID column is autogenerated identity one)? Without any controller code which can visualize your attempt I think it's very hard way to reproduce your intent.

Comment: @Tetsuya. Yes ID is identity. Because the same ProjectNo can have n positions. When I want to edit the second pos of a Project, later I select it by ID... I know that I have to place the Counter-Code into controller. And there into the HttpGet-Section. But I don't know the Syntax... In Access I can work with queries or Dlookup or DMax, but how in mvc?

Comment: @Tetsuya. Please look at my UPDATE 2...

Comment: I think you can query the last `ProjectNo` with `var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.OrderBy(a => a.ProjectID).LastOrDefault() + 1` then do something like `var retoure = new HN_Retoure_Stamm() { ProjectID = n }`.

Comment: Please look at Update 3 in my Post...

Comment: Is that `HN_Retoure_Stamm` & project table are using same table name? I afraid that you're using 2 different tables there, so that `Retoure_Nummer` has no records in `HN_Retoure_Stamm`. Again, I know what query that returned max value with `DMax`, but you need to mention in what table `dbo_Project` records are stored (for MVC project).

Comment: @Tetsuya. ??? No there is only one table in MVC + SQL-Server. On Server the table is named dbo.HN_Retoure_Stamm. In MVC the table is dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm. The third Update is the correct! Above there is an Access-Example, where the tables name is another!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153598/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-vegeta-77).

Comment: @ Tetsuya. Look please on my UPDATE 5 in my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you can do like this.

var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Last().ID

Comment: try this   var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Last().ID

Comment: var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.ToList().Select(a => a.Retoure_Nummer).Last();

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now it works with the following code:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    using (Stamm_Retoure dc = new Stamm_Retoure())
    {
        var n = dc.HN_Retoure_Stamm.ToList().Select(a => a.Retoure_Nummer).Last();
        var last = n + 1;

        var retoure = new HN_Retoure_Stamm() { Retoure_Nummer = last };

        return View(retoure);
    }
}
```

Thank you all :-)